# Bug in gcc, or extention in clang/MSVS

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

The following snippet compiles in clang and MSVS, but not in gcc.

```
template<typename T> class clone_ptr;

template<typename T, typename U, typename ...Args>
clone_ptr<T> make_cloned( Args ...args );

// note: everything not needed for example cut out, so
// this class is neither complete nor correct
template<typename T>
class clone_ptr 
{
public:
    clone_ptr() : ptr(nullptr) {}
    operator bool() { return ptr!=nullptr; }
    T* operator->() { return ptr; }
private:
    clone_ptr(T* p) : ptr(p) {}
    T* ptr;

    template<class T1,class U1, typename ...Args>
        friend clone_ptr<T1> make_cloned( Args ...args );
};

template<typename T, typename U=T, typename ...Args>
clone_ptr<T> make_cloned( Args ...args )
{
    return {new U(args...)};
}

// ----------------------------------------------

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Base
{
    int a;
    Base( int a=0 ) : a(a) {}
    virtual string foo() { return "Base "+to_string(a); };
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

struct Sub : Base
{
    Sub( int a=0 ) : Base(a) {}
    virtual string foo() override { return "Sub "+to_string(a); };
};

string testit()
{
    std::vector< clone_ptr< Base > > vec;

    vec.push_back( make_cloned<Base>(7) );
    vec.emplace_back();
    vec.push_back( make_cloned<Base,Sub>(5) );

    string ss;
    for( auto&& a : vec )
    {
        ss += a?a->foo():"<empty>";
    }

    return ss;
}

int main()
{
    cout << testit() << endl;
}
```

gcc complains:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'make_cloned(int)'
vec.push_back( make_cloned<Base>(7) );
note: candidate is:
note: template<class T, class U, class ... Args> clone_ptr<T> make_cloned(Args ...)
clone_ptr<T> make_cloned( Args ...args )
             ^
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'U'
vec.push_back( make_cloned<Base>(7) );
```

Is this a bug in gcc, and is there a workaround that only
relies on standard-compliant C++ ?

Comment: What version of GCC do you use? Have you tried the lasted, 4.9.2?

Comment: g++ --version gives `g++ (GCC) 4.9.2`

Comment: Indeed, it got an error with GCC 4.9.2 & is compiled with Clang 3.5

Comment: So please make a bug report on https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla

Comment: @sp2danny: You can give GCC 5 prerelease a try before filing the report.

Comment: there is a bug in bugzilla now: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87279

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed this seems like a bug. A workaround is to separate the default template parameter into a second function. Within `clone_ptr` you then have two friends:

```
template<class T1, typename ...Args>
    friend clone_ptr<T1> make_cloned( Args ...args );
template<class T1, class U1, typename ...Args>
    friend clone_ptr<T1> make_cloned( Args ...args );
```

and the definition is easy:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
clone_ptr<T> make_cloned( Args ...args ) { return {new T(args...)}; }
template<typename T, typename U, typename ...Args>
clone_ptr<T> make_cloned( Args ...args ) { return {new U(args...)}; }
```

Tested with gcc 4.8.3 and clang 3.5.

Edit:
After investigating I was able to get your code working with gcc 4.8.3 in two different ways:

1. Remove the template function declaration completely

   ```
   // this is not needed:
   template<typename T, typename U, typename ...Args>
   clone_ptr<T> make_cloned( Args ...args );
   ```
2. Move the default template parameter definition from the template function definition to the declaration:

   ```
   template<typename T, typename U = T, typename ...Args>
   clone_ptr<T> make_cloned( Args ...args );

   template<typename T, typename U, typename ...Args>
   clone_ptr<T> make_cloned( Args ...args )
   {
       return {new U(args...)};
   }
   ```

I still assume that this is a problem with gcc but this way your code works.